# how to open dialog for asking access location permission in react native

Tags: react-native, permissions, dialog

I need to open dialog for asking user to allow location permission for application.
Can I open this dialog manually? (espeically in IOS)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you look at the documentation for [PermissionsAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html) you'll see a line in the example that says

```
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
  {
    'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
    'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
               'so you can take awesome pictures.'
  }
)
```

This section of code will bring up the system dialog that asks for permission to use the camera on behalf of your app. Make sure you also add the required permission to AndroidManifest.xml in the `android/app/src/main` directory by default if you used react-native init.